# Xcode Too Slow to Work

Tags: xcode, performance

I've been searching this question for quite a while but still none of the solutions work, this time I got the error message, Xcode playgrounds don't work and if I make a regular iOS app project and run it in the simulator it will have the loading screen for around 15 minutes and then gives the error message: The operation couldn't be completed. (Match error -308 - (IPC/might) server died)

I've recently tried using my iPhone to run projects which works. Is there and way to make Xcode work normally.

I am using a Mid-2012 MacBook Pro Non-Retina with 4GB RAM.

Comment: What Xcode version are you using? Your mac is quite old and it might be unsupported.

Comment: @ EmilioPelaez I am using Xcode 8.2 (the most current version) and it seems like Xcode supports it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar errors (if overly slow apps are an error). Your problem is that one process awaits another and has an expire timeout. The other process takes a large time to load.

you might be able to solve this by adding a substantial amount of ram and moving the simulators to a RAM disk, alternately you might upgrade to an ssd.

realistically your best bet is buying new retina MacBook Pro. Thats how I solved it...

Comment: Thanks! I am planning on upgrading to 8GB of RAM and am hoping that will work.